# What are the permutations in S7 that commute with (12)(345)?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that I have $(\sigma(1)\sigma(2))(\sigma(3)\sigma(4)\sigma(5))=(12)(345)$. However, I've only found eight that commute with this permutation, how do I know if I've found them all?

Comment: Hint: the number elements is equal 7! / (the number of elements with the same cycle structure).

Comment: You haven't${}$.

Comment: Not sure what your notation $(\sigma(1)\sigma(2))(\sigma(3)\sigma(4)\sigma(5))=(12)(345)$ means unless you mean that $\sigma \in S_7$. Note that $H$, the subgroup generated by $(12)(345)$ is a cyclic group of order $6$. And the set of all permutations in $S_7$ that commute with $(12)(345)$ form another subgroup $K$ with $H \le K \le S_7 $. This should give you an idea of what $|K|$ might be.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131503/how-many-elements-of-s-9-commute-with-1234567), and several more of this type.

Comment: @SteveD So would it be 24 elements?

Comment: I think it is 12, actually.